# file include error in php

Tags: php, include

I am having this file structure and getting two errors:

```
php-
    |
    |=objects
    |    |=account.php
    |
    |=data_access
    |    |=connect_to_db.php
    |    |=query.php
    |    |=db_schema.php 

logic-
    |
    |=account_page.php
```

**First error:** now in `account_page.php` I am including this:

```
include_once'D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\account_share\php\data_access\query.php';
include_once '../data_access/connect_to_db.php';
```

The full path is ok but the second gets error:
Warning: include_once(../data_access/connect_to_db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\account_share\php\logic\accounts_page.php on line 3

```
   Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../data_access/connect_to_db.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\Development\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\account_share\php\logic\accounts_page.php on line 3
```

**Second error:** in `db_schema.php` I have this array:

```
    $schema['user_account']['table'] = "t_user_account";
    $schema['user_account']['user_id'] = "f_userId";
    $schema['user_account']['account_id'] = "f_account";
    $schema['user_account']['account_name'] = "f_accountName";
```

but in query.php I am getting an error at this line:

```
$query = "select * from " . $schema['user_account']['table'] . "  where " . $schema['user_account']['user_id'] . "=:userId";
```

here is the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: schema in D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\account_share\php\data_access\query.php on line 8
```

Here is the project structure (to make it easier):
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the include be `../php/data_access/etc`? But seriously, have you done any basic debugging (or searches for the errors) yourself?

Comment: I have changed it to `$dbSchema` and getting the same error :(

Comment: Are you sure the schema is included when trying to do the query? Seems like it wasnt

Comment: Here is the code:`include_once 'db_schema.php';
 echo get_include_path();
 Class Query
 {
  public static function getUserAccounts($db, $userId)
  {
   $query = "select * from " . $dbSchema['user_account']['table'] . "  where " . $dbSchema['user_account']['user_id'] . "=:userId";`

Comment: Look up variable scope. Easy solution would be defining the array as `global` in the function

Comment: i have included many times arrays in this way but it is the first time it's giving me this error....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic debugging methods and doens't show any research effort as well as minimal understating of the problem being solved.

Comment: @kingkero i have tried to add `echo get_include_path();` at many places but couldn't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include like this?

```
#account_page.php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$base_dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)  . $ds . '..') . $ds;
$file1 = "{$base_dir}data_access{$ds}query.php"; 
$file2 = "{$base_dir}data_access{$ds}connect_to_db.php"; 
include_once($file1); 
include_once($file2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the line art structure....

In

```
D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\account_share\logic\account_page.php
```

The path

```
../data_access/connect_to_db.php
```

resolves to

```
D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\account_share\data_access\connect_to_db.php
```

but you want

```
D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\account_share\php\data_access\query.php
```

hence the correct relative path is

```
../php/data_access/connect_to_db.php
```

But your screenshots seem to show something very different?

Comment: yes... I am totally lost in this. After echoing `db_schema.ph` to see if it is included, I see the echo string, but `$dbSchema` is still giving an error: `Notice: Undefined variable: dbSchema in D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\account_share\php\data_access\query.php on line 8`